# How can I implement double sigma insted of multi nested for loop in R programming?

Tags: r

I'm used to programming in C++ and Java, But I'm a newbie to the R programming. I just want to this nested implement this formula

[image]

My first thought was using nested for loop.But some people recommend to me, in R programming, avoid nested for loop and find functional ways.

So I tried to use this way

```
j <- seq(2,99)
k <- seq(j, 100) 
answer <- sum(k)
answer
```

But above code make this error message

```
Error in seq.default(j, 100) : 'from' must be of length 1
Calls: seq -> seq.default
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I find it more natural way using more mathematically using a concept of diagonal matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `seq` arguments are not vectorized.  So loop through it to get a `list` of `vector`s, `unlist` it and then get the `sum`

```
sum(unlist(lapply(j, function(.j) seq(.j, 100))))
```

---

Or call `Vectorize` which will call `lapply`

```
sum(unlist(Vectorize(function(x) seq(x, 100))(j)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your `for` loop solution, You can do something like:

```
j <- seq(2,99)

sums <- vector(length = length(j))

for (k in j){
  sums[k-1] = sum(seq(k,100))
}

answer <- sum(sums)
```